# lower bound of a trace quadratic form

Tags: matrix-analysis

i want to find a lower bound on the following expression:

$tr(AXA^T)$ in terms of $tr(X)$

where A is real $n\times n$ matrix and $X>0$ is positive symmetric. It seems that the following bound is to loose for deficient $A$ ($\mu_{min}(A^TA)=0$):

$tr(AXA^T)\geq \mu_{min}(A^TA)tr(X)$.

Any bound for this? thanks

Comment: Looking at diagonal matrices A and X where AX=0 makes me wonder: what could one possibly hope for beyond the trivial bound?

Comment: I missed the fact that X is strictly positive definite; however, one can easily find examples where AX is as small as desired while A and X have trace 1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what form of improved bound you could hope for.  If $v$ is a  vector
in the kernel of $A$, then adding $v v^T$ to $X$ will not change $A X A^T$ but
will increase $\text{tr}(X)$.  So if $A$ is singular, there is no
way to bound $\text{tr}(X)$ in terms of $\text{tr}(A X A^T)$ and quantities depending on $A$ alone.